# QTcpSocket: message not send from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, singleton, qtcpsocket

I know there is already many topics at this subject but noone to correct my problem...
I hope someone will find the solution.

Subject: I'm developping a multithreading game server.
Then, I overload TcpServer to write mine and so on...

```
void TcpServerCustomersHandler::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    ThreadCustomer* client = new ThreadCustomer(socketDescriptor);
    connect(client, &ThreadCustomer::finished, client, &ThreadCustomer::deleteLater);
    client->start();
}
```

I have written another class which overload QThread and wrote my connects.
In "question/answer" mode, it works. I receive message and I respond.

```
void ThreadCustomer::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Starting thread: " << m_socketDescriptor;
    m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!m_tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(m_socketDescriptor))
    {
        qCritical() << "Error creation thread:" << m_tcpSocket->errorString();
        return;
    }

    connect(m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_TcpSocket, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &ThreadCustomer::onDisconnected_TcpSocket, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(InstanceManager::instance(), &InstanceManager::readyRead, this, &ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager);

    exec();
}

void ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_TcpSocket()
{   
    QByteArray message = m_tcpSocket->readAll();
    //works...
    m_tcpSocket->write(message);
}
```

BUT as it is a game server, I want he could be able to send "notification". That means send a message to the player without receive anything before.
These notifications are send by a singleton "InstanceManager".

```
void ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager(QByteArray message)
{
    m_tcpSocket->write(message);
}
```

And here is my problem. When the "write()" is called, no message is emit and I have the famous message: "QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread".
I know I have this message because "write()" is called from another thread despite the connect.

Unfortunately, I don't find the solution to fix that. Does someone has an idea ?

Comment: I also have had a similar situation, what I ended up doing was writing it to a buffer and if the calling thread is the TCP thread, call write and otherwise wait on a timer which triggered every x ms. But I dislike that solution, especially for a game server

Comment: Are you sure that `InstanceManager::readyRead` fires for the same connection for which the thread is setup?

Comment: I don't understand your question Ton van den Heuvel.
If you ask if the connect is correctly done between InstanceManager and my function, so yes. I have a debug which is displayed

Comment: QTcpSocket is not thread-safe. I would suggest to use message queue filled by any thread and consumed by single sending tread

Comment: Also did you try connect(InstanceManager::instance(), &InstanceManager::readyRead, this, &ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager, *Qt::QueuedConnection*); ?

Comment: I tried to use a queue but I have others problems. If I want to do that, I need to create a second loop in the same class to send message. Also, I tried with a QTimer but same problem, the thread does not like that.
And yes, I tried all connection but no differences (auto, direct and queue)

Comment: If my understanding is correct, ThreadCustomer is created in thread where TcpServerCustomersHandler::incomingConnection is executed. Looks like you have to change thread affinity for ThreadCustomer and then you can use Qt::QueuedConnection. Btw, timer is not very good solution here.

Comment: Your understanding is correct :). What do you mean by "change thread affinity" ? Doing the connect directly in TcpServerCustomersHandler::incomingConnection ? Or make ThreadCustomer a child of TcpServerCustomersHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank to @wtom, I figure out a first solution based on queue.

I use a QTimer in my QThread to handle message and avoid conflict.
For others:

```
void ThreadCustomer::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Starting thread: " << m_socketDescriptor;
    m_tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!m_tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(m_socketDescriptor))
    {
        qCritical() << "Error creation thread:" << m_tcpSocket->errorString();
        return;
    }

    m_timerWritting = new QTimer();
    connect(m_timerWritting, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ThreadClient::onTimeOut_timerWritting, Qt::DirectConnection);
    m_timerWritting->start(500);

    connect(m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &ThreadClient::onReadyRead_TcpSocket, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(m_tcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &ThreadClient::onDisconnected_TcpSocket, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(InstanceManager::instance(), &InstanceManager::readyRead, this, &ThreadClient::onReadyRead_InstanceManager, Qt::QueuedConnection);

    exec();
}

void ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager(QByteArray message)
{
    m_listMessageToSend.append(message);
}
void ThreadCustomer::onTimeOut_timerWritting()
{
    if(m_listMessageToSend.count() > 0)
    {
        QByteArray message = m_listMessageToSend.takeFirst();
        m_tcpSocket->write(message);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is the better solution but that works :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember exactly how it is done, so it is more pseudocode, but the point is when you connect *InstanceManager::readyRead* to *ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager* (write on ready read event - is it intended?), *ThreadCustomer::onReadyRead_InstanceManager* will be executed in thread that created *ThreadCustomer*, the one that executes *void TcpServerCustomersHandler::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)*. It is not what you want. You have to change [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) of *ThreadCustomer* to thread that executes *ThreadCustomer::run()*

**Edit** ThreadCustomer is derived from QThread, right?

```
void TcpServerCustomersHandler::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    ThreadCustomer* client = new ThreadCustomer(socketDescriptor);
    client->moveToThread(&client); // in canonical way QThread and ThreadCustomer are different objects: client->moveToThread(&thread);, but may be it will work like this?
    connect(client, &ThreadCustomer::finished, client, &ThreadCustomer::deleteLater);
    client->start();
}
```

Comment: I confess the name "readyRead" is maybe not the best choice xD It juste contains a message to send.
I still have the same problem with this solution. From the link you sent me, that seems correct but it does not work...

Comment: parent of ThreadCustomer is set to nullptr. What have I to create in the right thread ? ThreadCustomer ?

Comment: there is one more problem, that makes solution I described wrong: *Warning: This function is not thread-safe; the current thread must be same as the current thread affinity. In other words, this function can only "push" an object from the current thread to another thread, it cannot "pull" an object from any arbitrary thread to the current thread.* http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread. I'll delete it later. I think correct and more simple way is to create ThreadCustomer in already running working thread

Comment: In what running thread do you want to create ThreadCustomer ? Except thread creates for each ThreadCustomer, the only running thread I have is the instance of application. (I tried to do a moveToThread on it but that not working either)

Comment: @Walterwhite Try do it like in example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Comment: The second example is exactly what I do right now. I am trying the first one, my ThreadCustomer does not overload QThread anymore but QObject and I do moveToThread in TcpServerCustomerHandle::incomingConnection. The problem is: how do you "pause" the thread. It's a QObject now so I don't have "exec()" anymore. It will stop just after starting.

Comment: QThread::run(): *The starting point for the thread. After calling start(), the newly created thread calls this function. The default implementation simply calls exec().* http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run

Comment: Indeed, IT'S WORKING ^^ Thank you so much

Comment: glad that it helped =)